# How to share authorization implemented in the server project with the client project in Blazor Web App Auto project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm using **Auto** mode in Blazor Web App. I tried to use `Authentication` and `Authorization` in the server project. But I cannot use authorization in the client project. I want to add `<AuthorizeView>` tag in some components exist in the client project. This tag is unknown in the client project. How can I use `<AuthorizeView>`tag in the client project?